# Compiling an ItoProcess

Tags: compile, random-process

I am a new mathematica user. I am trying to use the Compile command to speed up my RandomFunction output. The code looks like this:

```
test2 = Compile[{{ab, _Real}}, 
   Module[{counts, values}, counts = ab + 1;
    proc = 
     ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[
          t] == -x[t]  \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, 
      x[t], {x, 0.0}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
    result = RandomFunction[proc, {0, ab, 0.01}];
    values = result["Values"];
    values]];

abc = test2[1];
```

However, this gives me the following errors:
CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression {0.,-0.0293342,-0.113584,-0.18336,-0.183176,-0.1791,-0.291471,-0.256793,-0.177335,-0.0997472,<<91>>} should be a machine-size real number.
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 5; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

I don't understand the issues. Is the function RandomFunction even compatible with Compile? Please help.

Comment: Preliminary question: your `ItoProcess` is independent of the input, so why not defining it once and for all at the start ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Mostly because I am new and was trying different things out. It didn't change the output if I defined ItoProcess outside the Compile block.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Unfortunately, neither `ItoProcess` nor `RandomFunction` are among [compilable function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions), which means you will not gain any performance optimization by compiling the function, because the compiled function will have to call back the main kernel to evaluate this. I am not sure why there is an error message, though, but this doesn't change the main problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Domen. Makes total sense now.